# Jquery adding dynamic drop down list

Tags: jquery

We have some simple code as below. We have an add button on every row where it can add dynamic rows accordingly and this works fine. The problem now we need some more complexity where in the Serial column we need another add button where within this column we can add more then one drop down list too. So we are lost as to how to modify it to enable this functionality? Any idea?

```
<head> 

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my1.css" media="all" /> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.validate.js"></script> 

        <script type="text/javascript"> 

        $(document).ready(function() {


            function checkRows(form) {
                //$(form).validate().resetForm();
                //alert("Length : "+$('table.dynatable tbody tr', form).length);
                if ($('table.dynatable tbody tr', form).length > 2) {
                      alert("Call setup multiple row");

                }
            }

            var form = $("#form1");
            checkRows(form);
            setupFormValidation(form);

            var prot = $('tr.prototype').clone().removeClass('prototype');
            $(form).data('prototype', prot);

            var id = 1;

            // Add button functionality
            $("table.dynatable button.add").click(function() {
                var form = this.form;
                id++;

                // Get a new row based on the prototype row
                //var prot = master.find(".prototype").clone();
                var prot = $(form).data('prototype').clone();
                prot.find('[name^="id"]').attr("value", id);
                prot.find('[name^="locationFrom"]').attr('name', 'locationFrom[' + id + ']');
                prot.find('[name^="locationFrom"]').attr('id', 'locationFrom' + id + '');
                prot.find('[name^="locationFrom"]').attr('value', '');
                prot.find('[name^="serial"]').attr('name', 'serial[' + id + ']');
                prot.find('[name^="serial"]').attr('id', 'serial' + id + '');
                prot.find('[name^="serial"]').attr('value', '');

                $("#dynamicRow").find('tbody').append(prot);
                setupFormValidation(form);

                return false;
            });

            function setupFormValidation(form) 
            {       
                      //alert("validate :");        
                    $(form).validate();

            }


                      $('table.dynatable tbody tr select[name^="locationFrom"]').live('change',handleLocationFromUpdate);  
                      function handleLocationFromUpdate(index)
                      {
                          if($(this).closest('tr').next().length == 0 && $(this).closest('tr').prev().length == 0)
                          {
                            var nextValue = $('select[name^="locationFrom"]', $(this).closest('tr').next('tr'));
                            if(nextValue.val()==$(this).val())
                            $(this).val('');
                          }
                          else if($(this).closest('tr').next().length == 0 && $(this).closest('tr').prev().length > 0)
                          {
                            //alert("Last Field");
                            var prevValue = $('select[name^="locationFrom"]', $(this).closest('tr').prev('tr'));                            
                            if(prevValue.val()==$(this).val())
                            $(this).val('');
                          }
                          else
                          {
                            var prevValue = $('select[name^="locationFrom"]', $(this).closest('tr').prev('tr'));
                            var nextValue = $('select[name^="locationFrom"]', $(this).closest('tr').next('tr'));                            
                            if(prevValue.val()==$(this).val() || nextValue.val()==$(this).val())
                            $(this).val('');
                          }

                     }

                     $('table.dynatable tbody tr select[name^="serial"]').live('change',handleSerialUpdate);  
                      function handleSerialUpdate(index)
                      {
                            var sCheck = new Array ();

                $('select[name^="serial"]').each(function(i) {

                       //alert("VALUE IS : "+$(this).val()+"  "+$("option:selected", this).text() );
                       jQuery.inArray($(this).val(), sCheck);
                       if($(this).val()>0)
                       {
                         if (jQuery.inArray($(this).val(), sCheck) == -1) {
                                                   sCheck.push($(this).val());
                                             }
                                             else {
                                                alert("Serial "+$("option:selected", this).text()+" Selected More Than Once");
                                                $(this).val('');
                                                return false;
                                             }
                                         }
                });

                     }
            // Remove button functionality
            $("table.dynatable button.remove").live("click", function() {

                if ($('table.dynatable tbody tr', form).length > 2) 
                {
                var form = this.form;

                $(this).closest("tr").remove();
                }



                $('select[name^="locationFrom"]').each(function(i) {
                    if($(this).closest('tr').next().length > 0 && $(this).closest('tr').prev().length == 0)
                                      {
                                        alert("first Field");
                                        var nextValue = $('select[name^="locationFrom"]', $(this).closest('tr').next('tr'));
                                        if(nextValue.val()==$(this).val())
                                        $(this).val('');
                                      }
                                      else if($(this).closest('tr').next().length == 0 && $(this).closest('tr').prev().length > 0)
                                      {
                                        alert("Last Field");
                                        var prevValue = $('select[name^="locationFrom"]', $(this).closest('tr').prev('tr'));                            
                                        if(prevValue.val()==$(this).val())
                                        $(this).val('');
                                      }
                                      else
                                      {
                                        alert("middle Field");
                                        var prevValue = $('select[name^="locationFrom"]', $(this).closest('tr').prev('tr'));
                                        var nextValue = $('select[name^="locationFrom"]', $(this).closest('tr').next('tr'));                            
                                        if(prevValue.val()==$(this).val() || nextValue.val()==$(this).val())
                                        $(this).val('');
                                      }
                });

                var sCheck = new Array ();

                $('select[name^="serial"]').each(function(i) {

                       //alert("VALUE IS : "+$(this).val()+"  "+$("option:selected", this).text() );
                       //jQuery.inArray($(this).val(), sCheck)

                     if($(this).val()>0)
                       {
                         if (jQuery.inArray($(this).val(), sCheck) == -1) {
                                                   sCheck.push($(this).val());
                                             }
                                             else {
                                                alert("Serial "+$("option:selected", this).text()+" Selected More Than Once");
                                                $(this).val('');
                                                return false;
                                            }
                                         }
                });


            });

            jQuery('.dOnly').live('keyup', function () 
            {     
                 this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,''); 
            });
        });
        </script> 
        <style type="text/css"> 
            .dynatable {
                border: solid 1px #000; 
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }
            .dynatable th,
            .dynatable td {
                background-color:#ccc; 
                font-size:14px;
                font-color:#ffffff;
                font-family:Calibri;
            }
            .dynatable .prototype {

            }
            label.error 
            { 
                display: block; 
                color:red;
            }

            td { vertical-align: top; }

        </style> 
</head> 
<body>

        <form action="" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form1" > 

        <table id="table1">
        <tr>

                    <td>
                    Route Name:<input class="required text" type="text" name="routeName" id="routeName" value="" />

                    </td>   

                    </tr>
        </table>
        <table class="dynatable" id="dynamicRow"> 
            <thead> 
                <tr> 
                    <th>ID</th> 
                    <th>Location</th> 
                    <th>Serial</th>                     
                    <th><button class="add">Add</button></th> 
                </tr> 
            </thead> 
            <tbody> 
                    <tr class="prototype">

                        <td><input type="text" name="id[1]" value="1" /></td> 
                        <td><select class='required' id='locationFrom1' name='locationFrom[1]' >
                        <option value=''>Select Location</option>
                        <option value='1'>Loc 1</option>
                        <option value='2'>Loc 2</option>
                        <option value='3'>Loc 3</option>
                        <option value='4'>Loc 4</option>
                        <option value='5'>Loc 5</option>
                        </select></td>
                        <td><select class='required' id='serial1' name='serial[1]' >
                        <option value=''>Select Serial</option>
                        <option value='1'>Serial 1</option>
                        <option value='2'>Serial 2</option>
                        <option value='3'>Serial 3</option>
                        <option value='4'>Serial 4</option>
                        <option value='5'>Serial 5</option>
                        </select></td>                                  

                        <td><button class="remove">Remove</button></td>
                    </tr> 


            </tbody>     
        </table> 
        <input class="buttons" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /> 
        </form> 
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, for event handling I would use delegate instead of live so that you can define the event within a specified container: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

you could dynamically add the button with:

```
$('<button class="dynamic-button">my button</button>').appendTo($('#row_1'));

$('#mycontainer').delegate('.dynamic-button', 'click', function() {

    $(this).parent().append('<select><option>my dynamic drop down</option></select>');    

});
```

Comment: what is the core benefit of delegate it looks pretty much same to live? Secondly where to put the suggested codes and where do you get the #row_1 and also the #mycontainer? Thank you.

Comment: #row_1 would be the row in your table where you want the button to appear. #mycontainer would be a table or div tag where you want the event to bind within. The advantage of delegate over live is that the event does not have to bubble all the way to the document level and affords you greater control over your event handling.

Comment: I have tried this first  <tr class="prototype" id="row_1"> where I add the row an id and in jquery I tried prot.find('[id^="row_"]').attr("value", 'row_'+id); the values are not changing for the row id ? I hope I have clarified what I need the button beside the first serial on each row. So when user press the add button more drop down list can be generated only in that row box. Thank you.